# QGS Project file with multi-geometry shapefiles conversion to a single KML file with styles

Tags: qgis, convert, kml, qgs

How can we convert an entire QGS Project file with multi-geometry shapefiles into a single KML file with styles from QGIS?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 2):

When you convert Shapefiles into KML files and uploading them into google maps the style will change. It is pretty easy to change the google default style into the style you need.
About these multi-geometry shapefiles there is a possibility to merge them into one shapefile. They all need to be the same file type, you can merge to polygons layers, but you cannot merge polygon with line or point layer. Also the data in the attribute tables need to be similar, if they don't have the same columns it will not work.

If your shapefiles are meeting these conditions you can use the "Merge vector Layers" option at the Vector toolbar:
 [image]

Once you have clicked on this option a window will open, click on the three dots under the "Layers to merge" bar and choose they layer you need to merge.
[image]

Know you should have a new shapefile with the default name "Merged" that have the data of the original layers, at this example two polygons.
[image]

Take care to the fact that this new layer is only exits in your project, if you will not save it as a new layer and accidentally erase the project this new layer will be lost.